# I don't want to Send notification email to attendees when creating new event to o365 calendar using Graph API

Tags: charts

I don't want to Send notification email to attendees when creating new event to o365 calendar using Graph API.

I am adding an calendar event using "AddAsync" method but the notification emails are been send to all the attendees and I don't want to send that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.